# Java SDK Pull Basic Cloudwatch Metrics

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have this code but no matter what I seem to try, I always get a zero result for my dimensions and yet I can see it in the web CloudWatch interface. I don't know if it matters but I don't have advanced cloudwatch stats turned on, only the basic stats.

All I want is to be able to pull back basic metrics like RequestCount!! I am not interested in the cloudwatch stats for the instance, only the load balancer layer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strAccessKey = "AKIAI******";
    String strSecretAccessKey = "mtQk7******";


    BasicAWSCredentials oCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(strAccessKey, strSecretAccessKey);
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider oProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(oCredentials);

    String strSigningRegion = "eu-west-2";
    String strEndpoint = "https://monitoring." + strSigningRegion + ".amazonaws.com"; // monitoring.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
    EndpointConfiguration oEndpointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration(strEndpoint, strSigningRegion);

    AmazonCloudWatch oClient = AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(oProvider).withEndpointConfiguration(oEndpointConfig).build();

    List<Metric> oMetrics = oClient.listMetrics().getMetrics();
    for (Metric oMetric : oMetrics)
    {
        List<Dimension> oDimensions = oMetric.getDimensions();
        for (Dimension oDimension : oDimensions)
        {
            System.out.println("DN: " + oDimension.getName() + " DV: " + oDimension.getValue() + "NS: " + oMetric.getNamespace() + " NM: " + oMetric.getMetricName());
        }
    }

    List<String> DIMENSIONS_LIST = new ArrayList<String>();
    DIMENSIONS_LIST.add("LoadBalancer");
    DIMENSIONS_LIST.add("AvailabilityZone");

    GetMetricStatisticsRequest oMetricStatsRequest = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest();


    List<Dimension> oDimList = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
    Dimension oDim = new Dimension();
    oDim.setName("LoadBalancer");
    oDim.setValue("app/load1/2118d2a*******");
    oDimList.add(oDim);

    Dimension oDim2 = new Dimension();
    oDim2.setName("AvailabilityZone");
    oDim2.setValue("eu-west-2");
    oDimList.add(oDim2);

    Collection<Dimension> oDimColl = oDimList;

    oMetricStatsRequest.setDimensions(oDimColl);
    oMetricStatsRequest.setNamespace("AWS/ApplicationELB");
    oMetricStatsRequest.setRequestCredentialsProvider(oProvider);

    ArrayList<String> oList = new ArrayList<String>();
    oList.add("Sum");

    oMetricStatsRequest.setStatistics(oList);

    oMetricStatsRequest.setMetricName("RequestCount");

    Date end = new Date(); 

    oMetricStatsRequest.setEndTime(end);

    Date start = new Date(end.getTime() - 60*30); // Go back 30 mins

    oMetricStatsRequest.setStartTime(start);

    oMetricStatsRequest.setPeriod(60*30); // 30 min

    try
    {
        GetMetricStatisticsResult oResult = oClient.getMetricStatistics(oMetricStatsRequest);
        System.out.println(oResult.getDatapoints().size()); //Always "0"
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```